# sorting decimals with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to sort some XML data, i have followed W3s tutorials, but my code doesn't work, whats wrong?

```
  <xsl:for-each select="garage/car[colour='red']">
  <xsl:apply-templates>

<xsl:sort select="number(price)" order="descending" data-type="number" /> 
</xsl:apply-templates>

    <tr>    
    <td><xsl:value-of select="make"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="model"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
    </tr>


  </xsl:for-each>
```

XML example~:

```
  <garage>
  <car>
      <make>vw</make>
      <model>golf</model>
      <color>red</color>
      <price>5.99</price>
  </car>
    <car>
      <make>ford</make>
      <model>focus</model>
      <color>black</color>
      <price>3.66</price>
  </car>
    <car>
      <make>honda</make>
      <model>civic</model>
      <color>red</color>
      <price>15.99</price>
  </car>
</garage>
```

Comment: Are you sure everbody knows what your xml is like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to show all the red cars in descending price order?

It helps if you are consistent with your spelling of color/colour!  I am British and feel your pain!

Also you are mixing up the for-each and apply-templates (both work)

**apply-templates** method:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="garage/car[color='red']">
         <xsl:sort select="number(price)" order="descending" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="car[color='red']">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="make" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="model" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="price" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>       
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**for-each** method:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="garage/car[color='red']">
         <xsl:sort select="number(price)" order="descending" data-type="number" />
         <tr>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="make" />
            </td>    
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="model" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="price" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```